# best way to test an ASCII character in a python3 bytes object

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a bytes object and want to test if a particular ASCII character is in a particular position.

I nievely wrote code like

```
if b[i] == b"\n":
```

The problem is this doesn't work, it turns out after some experimenting with repr that while indexing a string produces a string indexing a bytes produces a number and comparing a number with a bytes always returns false.

I fixed this by doing

```
if b[i] == b"\n"[0]:
```

I have realised I could also do

```
if b[i:i+1] == b"\n":
```

Is there a reason to prefer one approach over the other?

Is there a neater soloution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A neater solution, perhaps, would be to use [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord), which returns a codepoint (integer):

```
>>> ord(b'\n')
10
```

That being said, the approach using a slice is quite fine too.  Just be wary that slicing out of bounds returns an empty string, rather than triggering an `IndexError`.